# handling asynchronous operations in react

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await, jsx

I want to achieve the following using React-jsx:

In one file, I have a function that makes a database request and returns some data. In another file, I want to call this function and then process the data. I want to handle this operation preferably using async/await as I have seen it should be possible to do, but I am not against a promise-based solution. Here is what I did:

```
export async function getData() {
  try {
    await request
      .get(url, (err, res) => {
        console.log('1', res.body);
        return res.body;
      }
  } catch(e) {
    return e;
  }
}
```

And in the second file, where I call getData():

```
import { getData } from './path';

async formatData() {
  try {
    const data = await getData();
    // some formatting
    console.log('2', data);
  } catch(e) {
    return e;
  }
}
```

And here is the result I get in the console:

```
> '2' undefined
```

suggesting that await hasn't worked. What I am missing?

Comment: `async/await` only works with thenable objects (read Promises). This syntax can't handle node style callbacks. You need to use promisified version of whatever `request` is. For example, `axios` or `isomophic-fetch`

Comment: Async/await is very close to Promises. In fact, they don’t work without them. If you want await to work, it needs to receive a Promise, otherwise it won’t do anything.

Comment: What is `request.get`, does it return a promise?